# Why cant VSCode using remote ssh server open file in the same directory?

Tags: python, ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I wrote a very simple test that is failing:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

While the file is very much there, it is giving an error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'`

How am I supposed to setup the VSCode env to recognize the remote file system during execution?
It does seem to be using the remote python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution I dont like. If I provide a fully qualified path the file will open, which means the interpreter is not running from the directory the code is in. Is there a way to tell the interpreter to run from a specific, or better yet, the script's directory?

This works:

```
import os

CWD = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

with open(f'{CWD}/file.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Run without Debugging" and set up a configuration in your `launch.json` that use the [`"cwd"` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_cwd). That way you can specify where you want execution to take place from.

But if the specific goal is to read a file that exists next to source code I would recommend using [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) to read the file as it will take care of the path resolution for you relative to the module.